# setInterval() speeds up when using multiple from object method

Tags: javascript, oop, setinterval

I have been having problems with my `setIntervals()`.  I know these issues appear a lot but I can't seem to work out what the exact problem with my implementation is.  Every time I instantiate a new `Obstacle()` it clears the set interval used to rotate the instance of the obstacle, and the next instantiation of the obstacle seem to rotate twice as fast!  I'm sure it's to do with scope but I'm a relative beginner so I'm not quite sure what's going on here.  Any more info can be provided.

```
var obstacleCount = 1;
function Obstacle(){
    this.angle = 0;
    this.id = obstacleCount;
    this.elPrefix = "cookie-";
    this.el = '.' + this.elPrefix + this.id;
    $('#game-wrapper').append('<div class="' + this.elPrefix + this.id + '"></div>');
    obstacleCount += 1;
}

var intervals = new Array();

Obstacle.prototype.roll = function() {
    self = this;
    intervals[self.id] = setInterval(function(){
        self.angle -= 3;
        $(self.el).rotate(self.angle);
    }, 5);
    $(self.el).animate({
        right: 1000
    }, 4000, 'linear', function(){
        $(self.el).remove();
        clearInterval(intervals[self.id]);
    });
};

var obstacles = new Array();

setInterval(function(){
    obstacleID = obstacleCount;
    obstacles[obstacleID] = new Obstacle();
    obstacles[obstacleID].roll();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: can you output self.id in your animation callback and paste the result here? That should give us some more clues.

Comment: Curious - I get a bunch of 5s, then a bunch of 10s, then a bunch of 15s ...

Comment: can you create a demo http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most games there is a single update loop that handles all of the update logic for your game. I would recommend using a single interval in which all objects are updated instead of giving each object it's own scheduled update via setInterval. You gain a few advantages from the update loop method:

1. Don't have to keep track of intervals.
2. Since since setInterval is not consistant with timing (it fires when the main script is finished executing and has some extra time before the next go around, but only if it's interval time is up. This means you cannot completely rely on it's timing being what you asked it to be.) you are better off having all your objects updated at the time so you are as consistant as you can be.

General pseudo code to get you started:

```
    initialize objects
    add all objects to an array 

    setInterval(updateObjects, 30);

    updateObjects(){
      for each object in array
         object.roll();
    }
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, `requestAnimationFrame` should be used instead of setInterval

Comment: Yes, requestAnimationFrame will give a steady 60 fps and is a better option than setInterval.

Comment: This worked thanks - I changed my code to this method and used request animation frame and it seems to be going much more smoothly now!